# Dvorak on Ubuntu 20.04 - No Pipe Key

Tags: keyboard, dvorak

I'm setting up a laptop (Dell P26E) with Ubuntu after using windows and WSL for a while.

I'm struggling to find the Pipe (vertical line) key.
According to the screenshot photo it should be were I would expect it, but instead, I get the '<' key.

[image: Here is what I see when configuring the keyboard]

Comment: From that pic it looks like it is beside the return or left shit keys. Hard to really tell.

Comment: The issue is that the key is not returned when I press it. I am getting the < character instead.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include which keyboard you have set in `Settings` > `Language and Region`